# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to replace the ui file with the py file.

### But there is an error.

```
C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5>python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x test.ui -o test.py
C:\Users\sungj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe: Error while finding module specification for 'PyQt5.uic.pyuic' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
C:\Python35\Scripts\pyuic5.exe -x test.ui -o test.py
```